# How to handle Unicode error on JSON objects in python?

Tags: python, json, unicode, python-unicode, try-except

When I call twitter API it gives me a JSON string of tweets

for example Example

---

data = {"created_at":"Mon Apr 22 22:45:05 +0000 2019","text":"Just confirmed! Mark Derdzinski, Data Scientist @dexcom is joining our Data Science panel! An alum of UCSD, Mark st\u2026 https://t.co/sPNgvMvx9t","extended_tweet":{"full_text":"Just confirmed! Mark Derdzinski, Data Scientist @dexcom is joining our Data Science panel! An alum of UCSD, Mark studies patient, commercial, & device data to generate actionable business insights & improve patient outcomes. #dexcom #datascienceday #techsandiego #ucsd https://t.co/89ktI7jKI3","display_text_range":[0,276]}

---

when I check the type it says str.
to parse i converted to dict using

```
a = json.loads(data)
```

From that I am trying to parse the ["extended_text"]["full_text"] to get the full tweet

but I got UnicodeError hence after looking at few threads i found out that I had to encode the string and used the below code

```
y = y['extended_tweet']['full_text'].encode(encoding='UTF-8')
```

But when I try to print(y) if the full_tweet contains links it is not clean and it displays as is.

So I planned on cleaning the tweet with the below code(found online as well #begineerlife)

```
URLless_string = re.sub(r'\w+:\/{2}[\d\w-]+(\.[\d\w-]+)*(?:(?:\/[^\s/]*))*', '', y)
```

I get Type error

```
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Please help me on fixing the issue I am not sure how I can parse a clean tweet.

FULL CODE is as below

```
def on_data(self, data):
        y = json.loads(data)

        try:
            y = y['extended_tweet']['full_text'].encode(encoding='UTF-8')
            print(type(y))
            URLless_string = re.sub(r'\w+:\/{2}[\d\w-]+(\.[\d\w-]+)*(?:(?:\/[^\s/]*))*', '', y)
            print(URLless_string)
        except KeyError:
            y = y['text'].encode(encoding='UTF-8')
            print(type(y))
            URLless_string = re.sub(r'\w+:\/{2}[\d\w-]+(\.[\d\w-]+)*(?:(?:\/[^\s/]*))*', '', y)
            print(URLless_string)
```

The try and expect method is used because 
Some tweets does not have Full_tweets so I just have to rely on ["text"] key on the dict object.

If you could help me in refining the code that would help a lot too.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possibly use the encoder function of the json.load https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 I tried this``` y = json.loads(data,encoding='UTF-8')``` but it again gives me TypeError and you please share an example?

Comment: Can you give an example of your original error and the tweet that went with it? And also what you are expecting as the output?

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 Please go to my github - https://github.com/stramzik/Twitter-Sentiment-analyzer
The Senti.py has the complete code
Tweet.txt has few example tweet json's.
I get the "TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object"  on all tweets because of cleaning which I am performing.

Comment: I'll take a look later and see if I can replicate.

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 Thank you. Let me know if you need anything.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't replicate it with the text file tweets or the one here.

Comment: You shouldn't call `.encode()` on a string here, and it's very rarely necessary actually. If you get a UnicodeEncodeError on `print()`, you should reconfigure your IDE/terminal to support UTF-8 and tell the Python interpreter about it (eg. throuh the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable).

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 You might unable to reproduce the problem because OP seems to be using Python 3, while you are apparently still working with Python 2.

Comment: I am _apparently_ on **3.7** but I did not get the same errors as op using their text file they provided so couldn’t help with the original error they were getting.

Comment: @lenz could you please guide me how to do that?
I am currently using ATOM to run the script.

Comment: I don't use Atom. The [Tech Support Cheat Sheet](https://www.xkcd.com/627/) applies (I don't want to call you a not-computer person though). If you're sure the problem is caused by `print()`, and if you can't figure out how to make it work in Atom, you should post a new question.

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 sorry for assuming wrong. My assumption was based on the fact that you linked to the Python-2 docs in your first comment.